# OpenCL not allowing me to select a device

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a problem with my code as when I select an option, I cannot seem to be able to select a device from OpenCL platforms. I am able to choose the device TYPE but once I select it, the program skips the whole selection process and goes straight to saying that I have an Invalid Option and that device was not selected. Below shows a code snippet of what my program does and a picture of the output that I currently have.

I coded as such that when I select the device, the program registers and checks that I have entered an integer before referencing the platform device. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
 bool select_one_device(cl::Platform* platfm, cl::Device* dev)
{
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;    // available platforms
    std::vector< std::vector<cl::Device> > platformDevices; // devices available for each platform
    std::vector<::size_t> maxWorkItems;     // vector for workitem size
    std::string outputString;               // string for output
    std::string choice;                     // user input choice
    unsigned int i, j;                              // counters

    try {
        // get the number of available OpenCL platforms
        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

        // find and store the devices available to each platform
        for (i = 0; i < platforms.size(); i++)
        {
            std::vector<cl::Device> devices;        // available devices

            // get all devices available to the platform
            platforms[i].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);

            // store available devices for the platform
            platformDevices.push_back(devices);
        }

        // store options as platform and device indices
        std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > options;
        unsigned int optionCounter = 0; // option counter

        unsigned int choice;
        std::cout << "Do you want to use a CPU or GPU device?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1. CPU" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. GPU" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter choice: ";
        std::cin >> choice;

    // for all platforms
    for (i = 0; i < platforms.size(); i++)
    {
        // for all devices per platform
        for (j = 0; j < platformDevices[i].size(); j++)
        {
            //checks the device type
            cl_device_type type;
            platformDevices[i][j].getInfo(CL_DEVICE_TYPE, &type);
            if (type == CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU && choice == 1)
            {
                //Option number
                std::cout << "Option " << optionCounter << std::endl;
                //outputs the platform and device number
                std::cout << "\tPlatform #" << i << " - " << "Device #" << j << std::endl;
                //outputs the device type
                std::cout << "\tType: " << "CPU" << std::endl;
                // get and output device name
                outputString = platformDevices[i][j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>();
                std::cout << "\tName: " << outputString << std::endl;
                // get and output device vendor
                outputString = platformDevices[i][j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VENDOR>();
                std::cout << "\tVendor: " << outputString << std::endl;
                //get and output compute units
                std::cout << "\tNumber of compute units: " << platformDevices[i][j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS>() << std::endl;
                //get and output workgroup size
                std::cout << "\tMaximum work group size: " << platformDevices[i][j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE>() << std::endl;
                //get and output workitem size
                maxWorkItems = platformDevices[i][j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES>();
                std::cout << "\tMaximum work item size: " << maxWorkItems[0] << std::endl;
                //get and output local memory size
                std::cout << "\tLocal memory size: " << platformDevices[i][j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE>() << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;

                // store option
                options.push_back(std::make_pair(i, j));
                optionCounter++; // increment option counter
            }

 std::cout << "\n--------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Select a device: ";

    std::string inputString;
    unsigned int selectedOption;    // option that was selected

    std::getline(std::cin, inputString);
    std::istringstream stringStream(inputString);

    // check whether valid option was selected
    // check if input was an integer
    if (stringStream >> selectedOption)
    {
        char c;

        // check if there was anything after the integer
        if (!(stringStream >> c))
        {
            // check if valid option range
            if (selectedOption >= 0 && selectedOption < optionCounter)
            {
                // return the platform and device
                int platformNumber = options[selectedOption].first;
                int deviceNumber = options[selectedOption].second;

                *platfm = platforms[platformNumber];
                *dev = platformDevices[platformNumber][deviceNumber];

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // if invalid option selected
    std::cout << "\n--------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Invalid option." << std::endl;
}
```

[image: undesired output]

The "device not selected" line comes from my main method's try block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The question is not related to OpenCL.
2. The problem is that you mix reading from cin via operator>> and using std::getline(). "cin >> variable" does not eat up the trailing newline, so when you call getline() later, you immediately get an empty string.

The obvious solution would be to use std::readline() when you ask the user to choose between CPU and GPU devices.

Comment: I see. I often get confused with that because I would think that operators and getline() works similarly. Thank you!